# Battlefield 3 - Roadkill in a Mobile AA?

Tags: battlefield-3

So, I was playing a round of Conquest Large on the Russian team, on Caspian Border. I'd jumped into the Russians' mobile anti-aircraft vehicle and begun attacking a hostile attack helicopter. I ended up destroying the aircraft and killing its pilot (I don't think there was a gunner) with the vehicle's main guns, and the game gave me a 'Roadkill' bonus. (Note - This helicopter was a ways away, and there was no one around me.)

Does anyone have an explanation for this or has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Perhaps you simultaneously ran over someone?

Comment: That wouldn't have been possible. I'm pretty sure I was in the enemies' out-of-bounds zone, and even if there was anyone, I probably would have shot them.

Comment: Also, I would have seen another "Enemy Killed" notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable a helicopter(or a jet) that then falls down and explodes it is treated as a *Roadkill*. I do not know if it's a bug or if it's meant to be like that, but it is like that.

A discussion about that can be found [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/621026-battlefield-3/60801444).

And a quote from there:

> ...
>
> roadkills from destroying air vehicles are just the people inside not
>   bailing out before it smashes to the ground, causing their death. for
>   some reason the game thinks it's a road kill.
>
> ...

Comment: This could have been it. I can't quite remember, but I think the helicopter did crash.